# In Java, what difference does it make if I pass method arg as - myMethod(myObjectReference) or myMethod(new MyObject)?

Tags: java

Suppose my method needs an object as argument, will there be any difference between the two? And which one should be preferred?

```
public static void methodOne(){
   myMethod(new MyObject());

}

public static void methodOne(){
  MyObject objRef = new MyObject();
  myMethod(objRef);
}
```

Comment: The first one won't compile. `new MyObject` -> `new MyObject()`

Comment: In Java it doesn't matter either way because Java takes care of deleting the  object when its out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you have no way to access the instance of `MyObject` after the method call, while in example 2 you can still access it since you assigned the instance to an variable.

So if you need/want to reuse the instance, go for example 2. If you just need an instance within the method, you can go for example 1 (though you could also just instaniate it within the mthod -> no argument at all)

The second example also gives you an opportunity to give the object a meaningful identifier. Sometimes that's useful for readability.

One more thing regarding the second example: If you perform changes on the instance passed to the method, those changes will persist within your `methodOne`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, they don't really make a difference. as you are passing them to a function. On the receiving end, they going to get received in specific object instance. and all the operations will be performed using the same in the function body.

For the code snip you shared the first approach would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a reference to the object you should use the second option, otherwise the first option would be better cause you'r going to create a "temporary" variable passed to the function and the JVM could do some little optimizations in memory because you don't keep a reference to that variable.
Plus, if you don't need a reference, I think the second option gives a more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with that object. If you want to use it after doing the method you need to assign it as an Object.

Something else, you need to:

```
public static void methodOne(){
   myMethod(new MyObject());
}
```

Otherwise it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the variables scope.

Every input parameter of a method/function is sent as a value. But if you sent a Object as param, you will sent its reference as value.

```java
public static void methodOne(){
  MyObject objRef = new MyObject();
  myMethod(objRef);
}
```

As your second example of code, objRef can be used on whole `methodOne()`. But, It is bad idea modify `objRef` on a function with void returns.

In your first example, you sent a new object (its initiated with its empty param constructor), but you cannot reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods do the exact same thing. The second one gives you the opportunity to give a meaningful name to your object to clarify things a little.